# rearranging / interweaving elements with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-grid

Is there a way with CSS, to kinda "interweave" elements?

Say I have react that generates a list of images, and a list of text.

The html would look like

```html
<div>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  <p>Paragraph 4</p>
  <p>Paragraph 5</p>
  <img src="image1.jpg" />
  <img src="image2.jpg" />
  <img src="image3.jpg" />
  <img src="image4.jpg" />
  <img src="image5.jpg" />
</div>
```

And I wanted them displayed like this

```html
<div>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <img src="image1.jpg" />
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <img src="image2.jpg" />
  <img src="image3.jpg" />
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  <img src="image4.jpg" />
  <p>Paragraph 4</p>
  <img src="image5.jpg" />
  <p>Paragraph 5</p>
</div>
```

I feel like it can easily be done in a React component, but I"m wondering if there's a way of doing this with either CSS grid or flex.

Comment: read about this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Before using `order` consider the impact it will have: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/CSS_Grid_Layout_and_Accessibility

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the order property of grid elements.

The following code should do the trick:

```css
div { display: grid; }

p:nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
p:nth-child(2) { order: 3; }
p:nth-child(3) { order: 6; }
p:nth-child(4) { order: 8; }
p:nth-child(5) { order: 10; }
img:nth-child(6) { order: 2; }
img:nth-child(7) { order: 4; }
img:nth-child(8) { order: 5; }
img:nth-child(9) { order: 7; }
img:nth-child(10) { order: 9; }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  <p>Paragraph 4</p>
  <p>Paragraph 5</p>
  <img src="image1.jpg" />
  <img src="image2.jpg" />
  <img src="image3.jpg" />
  <img src="image4.jpg" />
  <img src="image5.jpg" />
</div>
```

By default all grid items have an order value of 0 and the lower the order value is the higher the grid item appears. I suggest you use different selectors for the elements (add classes to them).

Comment: what if I didn't know how many p or img tags there are? is there a dynamic way of numbering them?

Comment: Yes. You can use your javascript to add the order property:
element.style.order = x
where x is the order value and element is the element in your javascript code